# Can you help me derive an equation regarding Pauli's exclusion principle?

Tags: special-relativity, pauli-exclusion-principle

I am writing a book entitled "Atoms" in which I must plow through much of the "old quantum theory" literature.   I am reading a paper by Pauli (the first of his two seminal papers that became the exclusion principle).  The book is both historical, and (to the best of my ability) rigorous.  I have come across an equation which Pauli states that ``it is known that''

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{r}\frac{d}{dt}(m\mathbf{v}) = \frac{d}{dt}(m\mathbf{r}\mathbf{v}) - mc^2
\end{equation}

The equation is used to derive the relativistic correction factor for the gyromagnetic ratio -- which he uses to show that the core electrons can't contribute to the anomalous Zeeman effect.  The assumtion is that the electron is in a Sommerfeld elliptical orbit at radius vector $\mathbf{r}$ traveling at velocity $\mathbf{v}$ close to the speed of light.

My copy of the paper is a little hard to read, but I think that I have the equation as written.  I can't seem to be able to derive it.     Any assistance will be appreciated!

The reference is Pauli, W., "Uber den Zusammenhang des Abschlusses der Elektronengruppen im Atom mit der Komplexstruktur der Spektren}, Zeitschrift fur Physik, 1925, 31, 765-783.

Comment: Did you leave out a scalar product in two terms?

Comment: *velocity $\mathbf{v}$ close to the speed of light* I think this is the key.

Comment: "I am writing a book..." Why?

Comment: Ghoster:  In the old German literature vectors were often written simply as products with the scalar product implied.  They also often enclosed both cross products and dot products in parnethses, assuming that one would figure it out in context.

Comment: @Ghoster in hydrogen $v = \alpha c \approx c/137$. Not fast fast.

Comment: @JEB I’m not sure that that’s the case at perihelion of a highly eccentric elliptical orbit *in Sommerfeld’s model*. Are you? In any case, I’m not the one who said “velocity close to the speed of light”; the OP wrote that. And I don’t see how the equation can hold unless $v\approx c$.

Comment: *In the old German literature vectors were often written simply as products with the scalar product implied.* OK, but I don’t see the point of using obsolete notation on this site, when what you want to understand is whether an equation is correct.

Comment: Do you understand why the equation holds if $\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{v}\approx c^2$?

Comment: Ghoster:  I used the equation as it appears in the paper since  that is where I am working from.   The equation does work if you set $v = c.  Its possible that Pauli made that approximation, since he is averaging the

Comment: Ghoster:  I used the equation as it appears in the paper since  that is where I am working from.   The equation does work if you set $\mathbf{v }\cdot\mathbf{v} \approx c$.   Since he is calculating an average correction (over a cycle of the elliptical orbit) it may be that is what he meant,  but Pauly uses the expression (if my translation is correct) ``it is known that.''  My German is sketchy, so maybe he meant something else.   Thanks for the input..  (Ignore previous comment).

Comment: @Ghoster: Egg on face.   In continuing through the derivation I came across an expression for $\gamma$ with a $v^2/c^2$ in which the old print and the poor quality of the scan  looked like $c^2/c^2$.  Thus the $c$ in my original ``translation'' is actually a $v$, and everything works.   Again, thanks for the help.